# Regular Expression Word Boarder

Tags: python

I got a word 'myword' and i want to find all those words in a file, that contain 'myword' but not those who contain it at the beginning. Can you guys tell me how to do it by regular expressions in Python? I bet that i must use Word Boarder expression somehow.

Comment: try `[^\s]+myword[^\s]*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\b` stands for word boundary, and `\B` stands for "Not word boundary"

Following regular expression should work:

```
import re
matches = re.findall(r"\Bmyword", file_contents)
```

Comment: Note that this will not give you the whole words, only "myword" + the character preceding it.